# Writing to a File on my website directory - Code is executing but file is not updated

Tags: java, file-upload

I am writing to a file which exists on my website . I have access to this file .
Below is the method code for the same :
Last Output on eclipse console is "3 Done writing to the file"

However , the file does not show the changes done by the code below
What could be happening with no error & all msgs printed in eclipse console ?

```
public static void writetoDirFiles() {
URL url ;   
   try { 
        
        url = new URL("http://www.indisofttec.com/network_black_list.txt");   
        
        System.out.println("1 Opening Connection to the File"); 
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();    

        yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
        yc.setAllowUserInteraction(true);  
        yc.setDoOutput(true);  
        
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                                       yc.getOutputStream()));  
        String fileContent = "window.io_global_name = 'BABLOO';";  
             
        System.out.println("2 Writing to the File"); 
       
        out.write(fileContent);      
        out.close();    
      
        System.out.println("3 Done Writing to the File");
       
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {      
       e.printStackTrace(); 
   } catch (IOException e) {        
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is sending data to a URL, which is ignored if there is not code to handle it on the server.

If your code is on the website server, you can use the `FileWriter` class to write to the directory of your website contents.

For example, assuming `network_black_list.txt` is in /var/www/html:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/var/www/html/network_black_list.txt"))) {
    writer.write(fileContent);
}
```

If your Java code is not on the website server, you will need to use a file transfer solution such as FTP or SCP.

Comment: Thanx @Heng Ye. That clears a thousand doubts in my mind .
I do have the code on the server which is writing to the the required file . 
Yes , FTP , we use to transfer files to our website server .

But was trying to do it through the URL Object . 
But once again thanx . Really appreciate your knowledge and help.

Comment: @ShekharWagh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Yes the answer has solved my problem. Thanx once again.